# How can i pass render props to children in React functional components?

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

i am using `react-final-form` I have a `Form` Component something like this:

```js
export function Form = ({ children, onSubmit, initialValues, ...props }) => {
   return (
      <FinalForm 
         initialValues={initialValues} 
         onSubmit={onSubmit}
         render={({ handleSubmit, submitting, pristine, valid }) => (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="space-y-6" {...props}>
             {children}
            </form>
         )}
      />
   )
}
export default Form;
```

I want to use this form component like this:

```js
<Form>
  ({ valid, pristine, submitting } => (
    <TextInput name="email" label="Email Address" type="email" />
    <Button text="Login" disabled={!valid || pristine || submitting} />
  )
</Form>
```

How can i pass the props `valid`, `pristine` and `submitting` to my childs so i can use it for e.g. disable a Button?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
{children}
```

Try this,

```
{
    React.Children.map(children, child => {
        if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
            return React.cloneElement(child, { submitting, pristine, valid });
        }
        return child;
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks, but nothing was rendered in the Form Component. I get the error: `Functions are not valid as a React child` How i can i solve this?